# How to replicate existing bricks to new node

Tags: glusterfs

Let's suppose that we have Heketi cluster with 3 machines. Then I want to expand our cluster to 4 machines. It's pretty simple, we just need to modify topology.json file, and run:

```
heketi-cli -s http://localhost:8080 topology load --json=/root/topology.json
```

All is OK, but question is - How can I replicate existing bricks to the new node(device)? Because now I have:

```
heketi-cli -s http://localhost:8080 device info d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961
Device Id: d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961
Name: /dev/xvdc
State: online
Size (GiB): 29
Used (GiB): 26
Free (GiB): 3
Bricks:
Id:1131bf531f5ec7fda0dffbb489aef539   Size (GiB):1       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_1131bf531f5ec7fda0dffbb489aef539/brick
Id:18e0d3b7f861e42a627ab641bfb58743   Size (GiB):1       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_18e0d3b7f861e42a627ab641bfb58743/brick
Id:24af2e1bd6156dad98c08fcb404c719b   Size (GiB):1       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_24af2e1bd6156dad98c08fcb404c719b/brick
Id:5dfdaf49a7ce99785575de4cd86f073e   Size (GiB):1       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_5dfdaf49a7ce99785575de4cd86f073e/brick
Id:64eba4eda4d361ad031b37050d3707d0   Size (GiB):1       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_64eba4eda4d361ad031b37050d3707d0/brick
Id:877f7b336ca3c565d2848c7e9fa1c697   Size (GiB):2       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_877f7b336ca3c565d2848c7e9fa1c697/brick
Id:b0e3d55f2a2a2ab8a8ace73894fffd0e   Size (GiB):1       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_b0e3d55f2a2a2ab8a8ace73894fffd0e/brick
Id:d0bf036ef3f24b8b42203168d83dd959   Size (GiB):15      Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_d0bf036ef3f24b8b42203168d83dd959/brick
Id:dcd35d3fd860897fc9a9b6b8a818a0e8   Size (GiB):1       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_dcd35d3fd860897fc9a9b6b8a818a0e8/brick
Id:f13cb21e3c1e753d0c8d7e2442240baa   Size (GiB):2       Path: /var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_d7e1d2b21251175a0f5886da62509961/brick_f13cb21e3c1e753d0c8d7e2442240baa/brick
```

And on the new node:

```
heketi-cli -s http://localhost:8080 device info d6bf7aeebeb1fbd6d3436937e6245628
Device Id: d6bf7aeebeb1fbd6d3436937e6245628
Name: /dev/xvdc
State: online
Size (GiB): 29
Used (GiB): 0
Free (GiB): 29
Bricks:
```

If somebody knows, how to resolve this, please help me.
Thank you@